# Why this fadein function not work when add filter css to code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this fadein function not work when add filter css to code ?

```
$('.ccc').animate({
    opacity: 1
    filter: alpha(opacity=100)    
}, 4000)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ny8p4/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma `: 1,` and quote filter value

```
$('.ccc').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    filter: "alpha(opacity=100)"
}, 4000)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ny8p4/7/)

Comment: Can you try `$('.ccc').fadeTo(4000,1);` @papmooo

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
  $('.ccc').animate({
     opacity: 1,
     filter: "alpha(opacity=100)"
     }, 4000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ny8p4/9/)

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery can handle this `alpha(opacity=0)`, `alpha(opacity=1)`, .. `alpha(opacity=100)` in `.animate`?

Comment: alpha(opacity=100) is used for `IE` & handled by Jquery itself